# Having an error in sql while creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

I am trying to create a table on my database. this is the error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL , `ctc` DOUBLE(5) NOT NULL , `ref` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `date` D' at line 1
```

My query:

```
CREATE TABLE `job`.`form_details` ( 
    `email_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    `number` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL , 
    `city` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    `skill` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    `qualification` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    `position` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    `exp` DOUBLE(5) NOT NULL , 
    `ctc` DOUBLE(5) NOT NULL , 
    `ref` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    `date` DATE NOT NULL , 
    `time stamp` TIMESTAMP(30) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Put some effort into formatting your query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `double`'s precision is specified by two arguments - `(M, D)` - M digits in total and D digits after the decimal point. A `timestamp`'s precision must be no greater than 6. So:

```
CREATE TABLE `job`.`form_details` (
 `email_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `number` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL ,
 `city` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `skill` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `qualification` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `position` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `exp` DOUBLE(5, 2) NOT NULL , -- Two arguments for the double's precision
 `ctc` DOUBLE(5, 2) NOT NULL , -- Here too
 `ref` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
 `date` DATE NOT NULL ,
 `time stamp` TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL -- Timestamp precision capped at 6
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: `time stamp` is ok personally I would avoid white spaces in field names.

Comment: @P.Salmon I used the OP's column names, just fixed the errors that were preventing the statement from executing. But I agree having spaces in a column's name is probably a bad practice.